# truncatechars with hyperlink

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a template for a Listview of blog posts in django.
For that I would like to shorten the posts. I am using
`{{post.body | safe | truncatewords_html:100}}` in my template. This tag shortend my text and appends an ellipsis.

The question is now: How would I change the ellipsis to a hyperlink pointing to the detailview?

I could not find anything in the documentation and I am aware of many jquery solutions.
Of course I could reimplement http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/444/ and add a hyperlink as an additional filter argument, but I am just wondering whether there is a built-in solution.

Comment: I would add a `Read more` link instead, for claritys sake.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I read your question wrong, but this might be what you're searching for:

```
<a href="{{post.url}}">{{post.body | safe | truncatewords_html:100}}</a>
```

I don't know if your post object has a url field, you might need to adapt that.

Comment: I already thought about it but it has certain issues: 1. Even if the post is short enough, it is still marked as a link (okay, i could enclose both <a> tags in if clauses, but it would look very ugly/php-ish ;) ) 2. I would like to have only the ellipsis as a link (a whole post as hyperlink looks strange)